# combining data/variables jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

```
var student = [{
    "fname": "Jackie",
    "mname": "Lee",
    "lname": "Li"
}, {
    "fname": "Ken",
    "mname": "Ryu",
    "lname": "Sha"
}];

for (var i = 0; i < student.length; i++) {
    console.log(student[i].fname + " " + student[i].mname + ". " + student[i].lname ? student[i].fname + " " + student[i].mname + ". " + student[i].lname + " , " : " ");
}
```

I am trying to combine names in the a `td` these names are from an array. I was able to make the names combine by above code. problem is on the last name there is still a `,` just want to get rid of the comma when there are no more names that will follow. I am bugged by this simple comma for hours. any idea is appreaciate.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/9hd0vfs8/)

Comment: `console.log(student[i].fname + " " + student[i].mname + ". " + student[i].lname + ((i < student.length -1) ? ", " : " "));`

Comment: What about using `.join()`? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hd0vfs8/5/).

Comment: I do just want to mention that the use of tertiary operator in this piece of code is ill-advised. It makes this string of code illegible. Rather spread out over multiple lines and store in a variable than using this many nested operators.

Comment: @somethinghere are you talking about markai's suggestion?

Comment: @somethinghere i would want his solution if it will not cause problem

Comment: @Pekka I am pointing at your original code's use of the tertiary operator. Its recommended to not use it in the middle of a string concatenation as it looks really confusing. Try to separate everything out in steps first - create a variable to store your string, add the first thing, then add the next, then use a tertiary operator to add one more etc... Then log the string stored in the variable. Do all these on separate lines with the `+=` operator. It will make your code easier to parse, errors easier to spot, and solutions easier to find.

Comment: i will practice doing the `+=` i am not used to it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One easy way is to build up an array and then using `.join(", ")`:

```js
var student = [{
  "fname": "Jackie",
  "mname": "Lee",
  "lname": "Li"
}, {
  "fname": "Ken",
  "mname": "Ryu",
  "lname": "Sha"
}];

var names = [];
for (var i = 0; i < student.length; i++) {
  names.push(student[i].fname + " " + student[i].mname + ". " + student[i].lname);
}
snippet.log(names.join(", "));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

It can even be more concise with `Array#map`:

```js
var student = [{
  "fname": "Jackie",
  "mname": "Lee",
  "lname": "Li"
}, {
  "fname": "Ken",
  "mname": "Ryu",
  "lname": "Sha"
}];

snippet.log(student.map(function(entry) {
  return entry.fname + " " + entry.mname + ". " + entry.lname;
}).join(", "));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question right than this should do it:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < student.length; i++){
  var name = student[i].fname + " " + student[i].mname + ". " + student[i].lname ?  student[i].fname + " " + student[i].mname + ". " + student[i].lname: " ";
  if (i < (student.length - 1)) {
      name += ',';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this bit of code

```js
var student = [{
  "fname": "Jackie",
  "mname": "Lee",
  "lname": "Li"
}, {
  "fname": "Ken",
  "mname": "Ryu",
  "lname": "Sha"
}]

for (var i = 0; i < student.length; i++) {
  var out = student[i].fname + " " + student[i].mname + ". " + student[i].lname;
  if (i < student.length - 1) {
    out += ", ";
  } else {
    out += " ";
  }
  snippet.log(out);
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: This answer has already been given. The drawback is the readability. The ternary operator in the statement obfuscates the code a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hd0vfs8/3/)

you should use like this:

```
var student = [{
     "fname": "Jackie",
         "mname": "Lee",
         "lname": "Li"
 }, {
     "fname": "Ken",
         "mname": "Ryu",
         "lname": "Sha"
 }]

 for (var i = 0; i < student.length; i++) {
     console.log(student[i].fname + " " + student[i].mname + ". " + student[i].lname + ((i < student.length - 1) ? ", " : " "));
 }
```